# Zookeeper connecting to localhost

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, apache-zookeeper

While running Pig Script which is inserting data into HBase i got following error.

```
2013-10-25 14:57:03,147 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO 
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2013-10-25 14:57:03,147 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2013-10-25 14:57:03,169 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x41ead7bb150092, negotiated timeout = 180000
```

Also when i see slave logs it says that unable to establish connection to master, But master says that connection is established successfully. Below are the logs of both:

**Master Log :**

```
zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=slave:2181,hadoop-master:2181,ubuntu:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/10/24 19:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server slave:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
13/10/24 19:51:56 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 104744@hadoop-master
13/10/24 19:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to slave:2181, initiating session
13/10/24 19:51:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server slave:2181, sessionid = 0x141ead77c250002, negotiated timeout = 180000
```

**Slave Log**

```
2013-10-24 19:51:32,174 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection: New election. My id =  1, proposed zxid=0x80000002a
2013-10-24 19:51:32,180 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager: Cannot open channel to 0 at election address hadoop-master:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
```

Below are my configurations:

**hbase-env.sh**

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name> 
        <value>hadoop-master:60000</value>
        <description>
            The host and port that the HBase master runs at.
            A value of 'local' runs the master and a regionserver in a single process.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/hbase</value>
        <description>
            The directory shared by RegionServers.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>
            The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
            false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
            true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
        <description>
            Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
            The port at which the clients will connect.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>hadoop-master,slave,ubuntu</value>
        <description>
            Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
            For example, "host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com".
            By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes
            of operation. For a fully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full
            list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.sh
            this is the list of servers which we will start/stop ZooKeeper on.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>
            Default block replication.
            The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
            The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
        </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

By entering command jps i get following output:

**At Master:**

```
104744 HMaster
91841 JobTracker
80184 TaskTracker
91475 DataNode
91222 NameNode
105062 HRegionServer
91747 SecondaryNameNode
104666 HQuorumPeer
```

**At Slave:**

```
11533 HQuorumPeer
2444 SecondaryNameNode
5970 TaskTracker
11756 HRegionServer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with your HBase config not being on the classpath when running the Pig script. One thing you can try is to set the zookeeper connection settings in the Pig script to see if it connects to the correct instance. If it does, you can add the HBase config to the classpath before launching your script.

Comment: i have solved the first problem(of zookeeper connecting to localhost) but its still showing me other errors(Connection refused at slave).